# Linux server compatibility questions

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, home-server, mono-framework, dasblog

I'm replacing an ancient server I have at home.  The old machine is currently running Windows 2000 *Server* edition.  It's an Active Directory domain controller, functions as a basic file server, hosts an [ASP.Net 2.0 web site](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org) (dasBlog), and I occasionally need to remote in to it when visiting places that won't have a vnc client installed other than the windows terminal services rdp client.  I'd like to put an operating system on new box that's not almost 10 years old, and so I'm wondering what a linux distro has to offer in the following departments:

- Can I run dasBlog on mono?  Where can I find help setting that up?
- Is it possible to migrate my Active Directory domain to a linux clone of some kind, such that my wife's laptop doesn't even notice (she won't be happy if I have to mess with it again)?  Where should I look for help with that?
- Can I set up a terminal services/rdp-compatible remote desktop solution? How?
- How do I set up file shares to replace the existing shares that will work with the defined NT security groups?
- These shares are currently also available via the web if you know where to go and can log into a domain account with the proper security.  How can I replicate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. dasBlog on mono - dont think so (third party libraries?)
2. migrate active directory - ive never been able to do this,, but the last time i tried this was about 2 years ago
3. No, RDP is microsofts proprietary protocol. X Server & VNC is all you got.
4. File sharing - Samba will take care of it
5. should be doable, but i think u need to adress #1-4 above first./

Answer (score 0):

All of those things are probably possible, but none will be particularly easy. If it was me, I'd be re-installing windows 2000[1].

---

[1] actually, if it was me I'd use ssh, wordpress, apache and nfs, but that's somewhat outside the scope of the question.